# HTML5 canvas animation and rotation

Tags: html, animation, canvas

I'm trying to create a new canvas animation of five circles revolving around a center point (similar to the solar system). So I've created the five circles and trying to rotate the canvas:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">


 var num=5, balls = [] ;

 function Ball() {
  this.r = 20;
  this.x =Math.random()*200;
  this.y = Math.random()*150;
  
 }
 
 function init() {
  
 canvas = document.getElementById("testCanvas");
  context = canvas.getContext("2d");
   
  context.clearRect(0,0,context.width,context.height); 
  context.fillStyle= "lightblue";
  
  context.save();
  context.translate(300,300);
  for(i=0; i<num ;i++){ balls[i] = new Ball() }
  setInterval(draw,50);
   
 }
  //function blank() {
    //context.fillStyle="white";
    //context.fillRect(0,0,context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
  // }
  
  function draw(){
   
   context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
   for(i=0 ; i< num ; i++){
    var Ball = balls[i];
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(Ball.x, Ball.y, Ball.r,0,2*Math.PI, false);
    //context.stroke();
    context.fill();
      }
   context.rotate(0.08);
   context.translate(0,0);
   context.beginPath();
   context.arc(0,0,240,0,Math.PI*2,false); 
   context.lineWidth = 8;
     context.stroke();
   }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
  <canvas id="testCanvas" width="600" height="600">
   Canvas not supported
  </canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

The issue is that the `clearRect` call doesn't seem to effective; sometimes I can see "trails" from one or more circles:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues here:

- Main reason: clearRect is used while the canvas is translated. This means it won't be able to clear the whole canvas. Always clear untransformed
- a save() is never restored() - it was probably intended for translation later on
- Use requestAnimationFrame to animate - this is much more efficient. Instead change the rotation rate.
- You can also add all arcs to the path and fill once provided the color is the same. This will speed up the drawing.

I made some changes below -

```js
var num = 5,
  rotation = 0,
  balls = [];

function Ball() {
  this.r = 20;
  this.x = Math.random() * 200;
  this.y = Math.random() * 150;

}

(function init() {

  canvas = document.getElementById("testCanvas");
  context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  context.clearRect(0, 0, context.width, context.height);
  context.fillStyle = "lightblue";

  for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    balls[i] = new Ball()
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);

})();

function draw() {

  // reset transforms before clearing
  context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // tramslate and rotate an absolute rotation value
  context.translate(300, 300);
  context.rotate(rotation);

  // draw arcs
  for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    var Ball = balls[i];
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(Ball.x, Ball.y, Ball.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    //context.stroke();
    context.fill();
  }
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(0, 0, 240, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  context.lineWidth = 8;
  context.stroke();

  // update rotation value and request new frame
  rotation += 0.04;
  requestAnimationFrame(draw)
}
```

```html
<canvas id="testCanvas" width="600" height="600">
  Canvas not supported
</canvas>
```

Comment: im unable to run the code which u provided...nothing happens...unable to find the issue :(

Comment: @sahilraj I put the init method in self-invoking code for the SO demo. Just remove those paranethesis if you use the original init call from html.